# Navigating back after a non-turbolinks request displays raw JSON on chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, turbolinks

The case (Chrome only)

1. I open my webapp
2. Navigate to another page (turbolinks)
3. Navigate to
   another page (no-turbolinks, e.g. form submittion)
4. Hit 'Back'

Instead of showing the previous route's HTML, i see a raw JSON. Note that this route, along with others, are configured to respond to both HTML and JSON.

Answer (score 4):

I added the following Javascript to my app and that solved it:

```
Turbolinks.pagesCached(0)
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
```